# Layer Slider - Box Shadow Window not working on iPhone/iPad

Tags: ios, css, iphone, slider

I have created a sort of 'window' that slides across to reveal more of the image, please see - http://sysmarketing2014.squaresystem.co.uk/

[image: box shadow window not rendered properly]

It seems to work across all browsers (apart from IE8 downwards - which I could also do with fixing) and even works on Windows phones and androids. It works in the Safari iPhone User Agent also.

It does not seem to be working on my iPad or iPhone however... they are both running iOS8

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue, it was to do with the box-shadow on iOS.

The iOS devices would not render the box-shadow with a spread size of 2000px. I found that the largest number I could input was around 850px.

Seems to be a problem specific to iOS

```
.ls-slide .peep {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 1000px;
  z-index: 100;
}
.ls-slide .peep:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2000px #72B626, inset 6px 6px 30px -4px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2000px #72B626, inset 6px 6px 30px -4px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2000px #72B626, inset 6px 6px 30px -4px #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 200;
}


.is-ios-device .ls-slide .peep:after {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 850px #72B626, inset 6px 6px 30px -4px #000;
}
```

I changed the spread value and problem solved.